# Wait function as while loop condition

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

What does this line do ?

```
while (wait(NULL)== -1);
```

This line is written inside a parent process after fork.

Comment: See the [man page for wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html).

Comment: This loop will keep the parent process from exiting until `wait` function returns a valid `pid`.

Comment: When you have a function that you don't understand, either type "man func" if you are on linux, or "msdn func" if you are on windows.
For C function, the man page is suffisant.

Comment: @Tom's "sufficient"?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, "sufficient". "suffisant" is the french word ... I make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I stand corrected! Thanks @interjay

From the wait man page:

> wait() and waitpid() The wait() system call suspends execution of the
>   calling process until one of its children terminates.  The call
>   wait(&status) is equivalent to: waitpid(-1, &status, 0)

From wait man page

> wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on
>   error, -1 is returned.

So what the code is doing here is waiting for any child process to terminate with an error, and we are ignoring the return value. (passing in a NULL ptr instead of a ptr to an int which the return value would be stored in).

Comment: You quoted the wrong bit about the return value of `-1`. What it actually means is that there was an error. What you quoted is about the parameter to `waitpid`.

Comment: Edited, thanks for the correction!